# How to get FBSDKAccessToken in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook SDK in IOS9 with swift but I am not getting the aceestoken. I have written the login code in **viewcontroller.swift**  file. I have done all settings is in my **info.plist** file also, but always getting nil value in accesstoken.

Here is my code

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKLoginButton.classForCoder()
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

   }
  func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
   }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {


 override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
           //outlet for fbsdkloginbutton
            @IBOutlet weak var facebookLoginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!
         var error:NSError?

                //check for error
                 if error != nil{
                                    print(error)
                                    return
                                }
                    //Check for the access token
                                if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil){
                                    print("USER NOT LOGGED IN")
                                }else{
                                    print("USER LOGGED IN")
                                }
                //set delegate for button
                        self.facebookLoginButton.delegate = self
                                //read permission
                                facebookLoginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile","user_friends","email"]
                             }
                        func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
                                /*
                                 Check for successful login and act accordingly.
                                 Perform your segue to another UIViewController here.
                                 */
                         if (error != nil){
                                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                                }

                                if let userToken = result.token{
                                    // GET USER TOKEN HERE
                                    let token:FBSDKAccessToken = userToken
                                    print(token)
                                    //print token id and user id
                                    print("TOKEN IS \(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)")
                                    print("USER ID IS \(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().userID)")

                                }

                            }
                            func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication)
                            {
                                // Called when the application is about to terminate.      Save data if 
                            }


                            func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
                                // Actions for when the user logged out goes here
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: How are you attempting to get the access token?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the delegate function in the ViewController. This [site](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/) is very helpful. HTH.

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    if ((error) != nil) {
        // Process error
    } else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle cancellations
    } else {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, email, name"])
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if ((error) != nil) {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            } else {
                // Do work in app.
                let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
                let loginProvider = CustomIdentityProvider(tokens: ["graph.facebook.com": token!])
                if let user : NSString = result!.valueForKey("name") as? NSString {
                    print("user: \(user)")
                }
                if let id : NSString = result!.valueForKey("id") as? NSString {
                    print("id: \(id)")
                }
                if let email : NSString = result!.value(forKey: "email") as? NSString {
                    print("email: \(email)")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
```

Returns nil if there is no Access Token